# Rails 4 Deep Nested Form with Cocoon Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cocoon-gem

Im attempting to use Cocoon to deeply nest dynamic forms in Rails 4

Im getting an error on the link_to_remove_association function from the 2nd level nested form (_milling_datum_fields).

ERROR: undefined method `new_record?' for nil:NilClass

Sorry for the mass amount of code.

My models of concern.

**Project**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company, inverse_of: :projects

  has_many :project_materials
  has_many :materials, through: :project_materials
  has_many :finished_materials, class_name: 'Material', through: :setups

  has_many :setups
  has_many :milling_data, through: :setups
  has_many :class_data, through: :setups
  has_many :screen_data, through: :setups

  has_many :notes, as: :notable
  has_many :tasks, inverse_of: :project, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks, :notes, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :materials, :setups, :milling_data, :class_data, :screen_data, :finished_materials, reject_if: :all_blank
```

**Setup**

```
class Setup < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :project
    has_one :finished_material, class_name: "Material"
    has_one :milling_datum
    has_one :class_datum
    has_one :screen_datum

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :milling_datum, :class_datum, :screen_datum, :finished_material, reject_if: :all_blank
end
```

**MillingDatum**

```
class MillingDatum < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :setup
    has_many :notes, as: :notable
```

My Views

**projects/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>
...
 <div class="col-lg-6">
    <%= f.fields_for :setups do |setup| %>
      <%= render 'layouts/setup_fields', f: setup %>
    <% end %> 
    <div class="links float-e-margins">
      <%= link_to_add_association 'add setup', f, :setups, partial: 'layouts/setup_fields', class: "btn btn-outline btn-default btn-xs" %>
    </div>    
  </div>
...
```

**layouts/_seutp_fields.html.erb**

```
<div class="nested-fields">
...
  <div class="col-lg-6">
      <%= f.fields_for :milling_data do |md| %>
        <%= render 'layouts/milling_datum_fields', f: md %>
      <% end %> 
      <div class="links float-e-margins">
        <%= link_to_add_association 'add milling data', f, :milling_data, partial: 'layouts/milling_datum_fields', class: "btn btn-outline btn-default btn-xs" %>
      </div>    
    </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
      <%= f.fields_for :class_data do |cd| %>
        <%= render 'layouts/class_datum_fields', f: cd %>
      <% end %> 
      <div class="links float-e-margins">
        <%= link_to_add_association 'add class data', f, :class_data, partial: 'layouts/class_datum_fields', class: "btn btn-outline btn-default btn-xs" %>
      </div>    
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <%= f.fields_for :screen_data do |sd| %>
        <%= render 'layouts/screen_datum_fields', f: sd %>
      <% end %> 
      <div class="links float-e-margins">
        <%= link_to_add_association 'add screen data', f, :screen_data, partial: 'layouts/screen_datum_fields', class: "btn btn-outline btn-default btn-xs" %>
      </div>    
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <%= f.fields_for :finished_materials do |fm| %>
        <%= render 'material_fields', f: fm %>
      <% end %> 
      <div class="links float-e-margins">
        <%= link_to_add_association 'add finished material', f, :finished_materials, partial: 'projects/material_fields', class: "btn btn-outline btn-default btn-xs" %>
      </div>    
    </div>
  </div>
      <%= link_to_remove_association "X", f, class: "btn btn-outline btn-danger btn-xs pull-right" %>

  </div>
</div>
```

**layouts/_milling_datum_fields.html.erb**

```
<div class="nested-fields">
...
 <div class="field form-group">
        <%= f.label :rate_test_lbs_hr %><br>
        <%= f.number_field :rate_test_lbs_hr, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <%= link_to_remove_association "X", f, class: "btn btn-outline btn-danger btn-xs pull-right" %>
  </div>
```

**projects_controller** strong params

```
def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:name, :scheduled_start_date, :estimated_end_date, :employees_needed, :incoming_packaging, :final_product_packaging, :sample_instructions, :project_description, :project_type, :building_id, :paid_status, :material_total_weight_lbs, :shifts, :shift_hrs, :rate_lb_hr, :company_id,
        materials_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :material_type, :name, :moisture, :density_g_cm3, :msds_url],
        notes_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :content, :notable_id, :notable_type],
        setups_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :project_id, 
          milling_data_attributes:[ 
            :id, :_destroy, :date_milled, :mill_model, :mill_liner_type, :mill_tlgs_set, :mill_rpm, :mill_amps, :mill_class_rpm, :mill_class_amps, :feeder_model, :feeder_speed_setting, :feeder_auger_diam_inch, :air_pressure_iw_mill_out, :air_pressure_iw_mill_in, :air_pressure_iw_dustcollector_baghouse, :air_pressure_iw_dustcollector_exit, :air_pressure_iw_blower_out, :temp_ambeint, :temp_mill_out, :temp_prod_out, :rate_test_total_lbs, :rate_test_total_time, :rate_test_lbs_hr, :setup_id
          ],
          screen_data_attributes:[
            :id, :_destroy, :screen_base_pci_id, :top_weight, :bottom_weight, :weight_lead, :deck_count, :screen_1_mesh, :screen_2_mesh, :screen_3_mesh, :setup_id
          ],
          class_data_attributes: [
           :id, :_destroy, :rate_lb_hr, :class_pci_id, :rpm, :secondary_air_setting, :ap_iw_secondary_air_in, :ap_iw_main_exit, :ap_iw_main_entrance, :setup_id
          ],
          finished_materials_attributes: [
            :id, :_destroy, :material_type, :moisture, :name, :msds_url, :density_g_cm3, :setup_id 
          ]
        ])
    end
```

Ive scoured the similar threads on the Internet but I can not figure it out.
Im starting to think I have something wrong in my models.
Would it help if I post my `projects_controller.rb` ?
Thanks for helping.

Comment: I extracted the double nested milling_datum into its own form under setup and still had the same problem. I change the association for Setup from `has_one :milling_datum` to `has_many :milling_data` and it works

Comment: It has to do with how I did my strong parameters. has_one belongs_to associations will have singular named strong params. `milling_data_attributes` to `milling_datum_attributes`, which is the singular version.

Comment: in your projects_controller, are you building project.setups, and setup.milling_data for each of those?

Comment: @BryanAsh Yea I do, I have it working as not being double nested. Ill post an answer when I double nest it.

Comment: Mmmm a bit confused to which error you are now seeing: from the comments I assume 1) the original error is fixed, and 2) the code has changed? Also it is unclear what the current problem is? Note: in general the error you mentioned is related to either a missing `accepts_nested_attributes_for` or declaring `fields_for` instead of `f.fields_for`.

Comment: @nathanvda I did fix this I think. I pulled out the double nested form and the problem persisted in the milling_datum_fields. Then I seen my strong params were wrong according to how my associations were setup. See they are plural, well they are suppose to be singular because the relation goes Project ->has_many->Setups->has_one->milling_datum. When i switched milling_data_attributes to milling_datum_attributes all was well. I have yet to put it back to double nested.

Comment: @nathanvda thanks a bunch for the gem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright Guys I figured out my particular problem.

The issue was that my nested strong params defined in my parent object controller (projects_controller) were not correctly pluralized according the the relationship definitions in my models.

Giving me the error: ERROR: undefined method `new_record?' for nil:NilClass

I had

```
params.require(:project).permit(:name, :scheduled_start_date, :estimated_end_date, :employees_needed, :incoming_packaging, :final_product_packaging, :sample_instructions, :project_description, :project_type, :building_id, :paid_status, :material_total_weight_lbs, :shifts, :shift_hrs, :rate_lb_hr, :company_id,
        setups_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :project_id, 
          milling_data_attributes:[ 
            :id, :_destroy, :date_milled, :mill_model, :mill_liner_type, :mill_tlgs_set, :mill_rpm, :mill_amps, :mill_class_rpm, :mill_class_amps, :feeder_model, :feeder_speed_setting, :feeder_auger_diam_inch, :air_pressure_iw_mill_out, :air_pressure_iw_mill_in, :air_pressure_iw_dustcollector_baghouse, :air_pressure_iw_dustcollector_exit, :air_pressure_iw_blower_out, :temp_ambeint, :temp_mill_out, :temp_prod_out, :rate_test_total_lbs, :rate_test_total_time, :rate_test_lbs_hr, :setup_id
          ])
```

Since my relations go `Project has_many->Setups has_one->Milling_datum` I need to change the pluralization of `milling_data_attributes` to `milling_datum_attributes`

From looking into this problem I have seen the most common errors with the Coccoon Gem

1. The inclusion of nested strong params and the correct pluralization of each object according to the relationship defined in the models.
2. Having your parent model define the correct accepts_nested_attributes_for with the correct pluralization of each object according to the relationship defined in the models.
3. Using the correct structure of partials, html, and coccoon provided functions according to the cocoon instructions.